# How to handle comma (,) in CSV cell data in Bash or Python

Tags: python, bash, csv

I am working on an automation script in Bash.

I am downloading the CSV file from Google drive and rearrange the columns on the basis of predefined template. Column positions can vary in CSV files. I have done that already but the CSV file has columns which have a comma inside the cell data. Now the issue is when rearranging, the CSV data is messed up. There are 29 columns in CSV I am showing the specific columns here in the example of the data.

```
Business Name,Address 1,SIC Description,Tags

CANNON CONSULTING  LLC,56 DOUBLOON DR,"Business Consulting, Nec",m1096465.output.lsb
DLM MAINTENANCE INC,4157 UPPERLINE ST,"Building Maintenance Services, Nec",m1096465.output.lsb
PELICAN PLUMBING REPAIRS LLC,128 NEPTUNE RD,Plumbing Contractors,m1096465.output.lsb
CRATING PACKING & SHIPPING LLC,39131 MILLER RD,Packing Goods For Shipping,m1096465.output.lsb
PRO TECH AUTOMOTIVE,40167 HIGHWAY 190 E B,GENERAL AUTOMOTIVE REPAIR SHOPS,"m1096465.output.lsb, gppo229715-2"
AWAKEN WELLNESS STUDIO LLC,110 DOUBLOON DR,"Health and Allied Services, Nec",m1096465.output.lsb
R M JEAUXNES PROPERTIES,433 NIGHTHAWK DR,Nonresidential Building Operators,m1096465.output.lsb
TEXAS TRANSPORT TOWING LLC,228 HOLLOW ROCK CT,"Transportation Services, Nec",m1096465.output.lsb
GENTLE TOUCH PERSONAL CARE,405 FOXCROFT DR,"NURSING AND PERSONAL CARE, NEC","m1096465.output.lsb, gppo229715-2"
REKERS MAINTENANCE LLC,162 LAKE D ESTE DR,"Building Maintenance Services, Nec",m1096465.output.lsb
```

I am using **awk** to re order the columns like this and using numbers not column names

`awk -F, '{ print $'$contact_id'","$'$business_name'",..... }' $file_name > tmp_awk.csv`

My first priority is to solve this using Bash but I can also include Python script so I have the option of Python too.

Comment: If using awk, use GNU awk and instead of `FS` (`-F,`) check out `FPAT`: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: Handling proper CSV quoting with awk, sed et al. is going to be a pain. Do yourself a favour and use the `csv` module in Python. Or bring out the heavy artillery and use Pandas.

Comment: It is a part of requirements that not to use any utility.

Comment: If Python is an option, it comes with a csv module that handles with data with no problem. I have just tested it, and all rows have exactly 4 fields. But as I do not know what the output should be I cannot propose any code...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @SergeBallesta output will be like
SIC Description, Address 1, Tags, Business Name

Comment: do you want to reorder by name or by number?

Comment: @Fravadona by number

Comment: You can't use _awk_  in this case, because commas (and newlines!) can also be part of a field. Use one of the many programming languages which ship with a CSV parser (Ruby, Perl, Python,....).

Answer (score 3):

A Python script using the csv module could be as simple as:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, ['SIC Description', 'Address 1',
                                'Tags', 'Business Name'])
    _ = wr.writeheader()
    _ = wr.writerows(rd)
```

---

If you want to reorder by column numbers it is even simpler

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    neworder = [2, 1, 3, 0]
    length = len(neworder)
    wr.writerows([row[neworder[i]] for i in range(length)] for row in rd)
```

Comment: in csv header column names and position is variable, i am using the column numbers instead of names.

Comment: @MohammadUmarSattar: Please see my edit...

Comment: does this work for Python 2.7.12. If no, can you give for the specified version. I am not aware of Python.

Comment: @MohammadUmarSattar This code is for Python 3. The csv module exists in Python 2.7 with slightly different semantics. Anyway, this is a *developper grade* script that is indended to be used by a Python user, because the file names and column ordering are directly written in the source code. I will not advise you to use it if you do not intend to use Python, and if you want to use Python, I strongly urge you to use a Python 3 version.

Comment: can't update the version, this will disturb the other things on the server. Have to work with Python 2.7.12. Further I will pass the column ordering and file names from Bash.

Comment: @MohammadUmarSattar: Most systems can have multiple Python versions side by side. And porting that script to Python 2.7 is not hard. The real problem is that if you do not know Python, you need a *professional grade* script with command line arguments and error conditions processing. And enough testing to make sure that it will not suddenly break with a cryptic message facing a real file. This is much more than what I can provide in a SO answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you can install `pandas` this becomes very easy.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv') # handles commas inside quotes
df_ordered = df[list_with_column_names] # rearranges columns
df_ordered.to_csv('out.csv') # writes output
```

Of course you can do everything with the builtin `csv` module, too. Only the column reordering isn't quite as trivial.

Comment: Pandas is indeed much more powerful. But reordering columns with a DictReader and a DictWriter is quite easy too, even if not as easy that the Pandas way.

Comment: And if you are not already using Pandas anyway, installing 100+MB of dependencies for the tiny amount of syntactic sugar it brings to this particular task is just irresponsible.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('tmp_awk.csv',sep=',')
//head of the data / few rows
data.head()
// rearrange the data
data[['column name 1','column name 2', 'column name 3']] // so on till column name you need
```

In bash:

```
INPUT=tmp_awk.cvs
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read flname dob ssn tel status
do
    echo "Name : $flname"
    echo "DOB : $dob"
    echo "SSN : $ssn"
    echo "Telephone : $tel"
    echo "Status : $status"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: in csv header names and position is variable.

Comment: The Bash code is inherently unable to cope with CSV quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Python is definitely the way here, as it comes with basically all systems.

As mentioned by others, `csv` is built-in and requires no additional install.

```py
import csv

with open("tmp.csv", "r") as file:
    content = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    with open("out.csv", "w") as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in content:
            if row:
                writer.writerow([row[2], row[1], row[3], row[0]])
```